# A regex capturing multiple groups starting with a pattern

Tags: regex, dart

I am trying to figure out a regex that would capture multiple groups in a string where each group is defined as follows:

1. The group's title starts with `${{`
2. An optional string may follow
3. The group's title ends with `}}`
4. Optional content may follow the title

An example would be
`'${{an optional title}} some optional content'`

Here are some examples of inputs and expected results

Input 1: `'${{}} some text '`

Result 1: `['${{}} some text ']`

Input 2: `'${{title1}} some text1 ${{title 2}} some text2'`

Result 2: `['${{title1}} some text1 ', '${{title 2}} some text2']`

Input 3 (no third group as the second ending curly bracket is missing)

`'${{title1}} some text1 ${{}} some text2  ${{title2} some text3'`

Result 3 `['${{title1}} some text1 ', '${{}} some text2  ${{title2} some text3']`

Input 4 (a group with empty content immediately followed by another group)

`'${{title1}}${{}} some text2'`

Result 4 `['${{title1}}', '${{}} some text2']`

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: What you described sounds to me like \${{.*}}.* am I understanding what you're after correctly?

Comment: Not exactly. The regex you type will produce just one match starting from the first matching ${{ found in the input string ending at the end of the string (greedy match).
When slightly modified to \${{.*?}} it will produce three matches but each matching group will only contain the title. Try it on regexpal.com against  ${{title1}}content1${{}}content2${{title3}}content3
 Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using?

Comment: I my code is written in Dart, but if you can find the right regex for js I guess it will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with Lookaheads. Try the following pattern:

```
\$\{\{.*?\}\}.*?(?=\$\{\{.*?\}\}|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8JvusW/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```regex
\$\{\{.*?\}\}    # Matches a "group" (i.e., "${{}}") containing zero or more chars (lazy).
.*?              # Matches zero or more characters after the "group" (lazy).
(?=              # Start of a positive Lookahead.
  \$\{\{.*?\}\}  # Ensure that the match is either followed by a "group"...
|                # Or...
  $              # ..is at the end of the string.
)                # Close the Lookahead.
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I was very close though, looking at lookaheads :D

Comment: @hicnar If you had tried something, you should probably include it in the question. It helps answerers understand the problem better and also lowers the chances of your question being closed for lack of effort.

Comment: Lookahead is supported in Dart RegExps (which are JavaScript RegExp compatible). You should escape `{` as well, though, it's an accident of backwards compatibility that makes it not a syntax error to use `{`, `}` which isn't a correct range.

Comment: @lrn Is this something special about JavaScript's regex? AFAIK, curly braces need to be escaped unless you want to match something like `{1}` literally.

Comment: Dart uses the V8 regular expression parser which is more permissive than what the ECMAScript [regular expression grammar](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-patterns) requires. For example it allows `{a}` as a regular expression, something which the grammar *does not* have a production for. Browsers have traditionally been more permissive than the actual specification, and since Dart for the web uses the browser's regexps, we decided to allow the same things natively. It's still not *correct*. An ECMAScript correct regexp *must* escape all `{` characters outside of char-ranges.